# Apache: Error configuring application listener

Tags: java, apache, hibernate

I'm facing with this problem when I try to run the application:

> WARNING: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'source'
>   to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:CongressApp' did not find a matching
>   property. May 13, 2014 1:35:26 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart SEVERE: Error
>   configuring application listener of class
>   org.apache.catalina.deploy.ApplicationListener@bdeab
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.iss.congress.core.util.CongressContextListener    at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:527)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:509)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:137)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4854)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:656)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1635)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
>
> May 13, 2014 1:35:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
>   listenerStart SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class
>   org.apache.catalina.deploy.ApplicationListener@6a5b20
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.iss.congress.core.util.CongressHttpSessionListener    at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:527)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:509)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:137)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4854)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:656)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1635)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
>
> May 13, 2014 1:35:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
>   listenerStart SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class
>   org.apache.catalina.deploy.ApplicationListener@1bacb12
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.iss.congress.core.util.HibernateListener  at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:527)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:509)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:137)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4854)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:656)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1635)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

In web.xml listeners are configured in this manner:

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>com.iss.congress.core.util.CongressContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.iss.congress.core.util.CongressHttpSessionListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <listener>
        <display-name>Hibernate Session Listener</display-name>
        <listener-class>com.iss.congress.core.util.HibernateListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a case of `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.iss.congress.core.util.HibernateListener` which means that the class `HibernateListener` is not present in the class path. Make sure that the jar containing this class is present in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder of your application.

If the class is present in the src folder then check the package name. Package names/Class Names are case-sensitive.

Comment: Thank you for reply.
Unfortunately I checked the spelling and I found no problem

Comment: I tried to delete the server on Eclipse IDE and, then, create it again. This steps fixed the problem.
Could you explain why did this problem occure?

Comment: This could have been a problem with caching. Rarely what does happen is that eclipse+tomcat caches an earlier version of the war partially (due to thread hold). Thus resulting in this problem. If you face a situation where by your changes are not reflected you can also try to `Clea Tomcat Work Directory` next time.

Answer (score 1):

There can be any of the following reasons:

1. Either, your class file is not available on specified location (check your package_name/class_file_name.java)
2. **OR, your file exist at specified location but there is an error in your file, that could be built (generate class file)**

(for me, the reason for an issue was point no. 2.) The root cause of an issue was, I changed (upgraded) version of rest libraries, which caused an issue with existing class files.

---

I resolved an issue by adding/selecting proper apache tomcat server.

> Project Properties => Java Build Path => Add Library => Select `Server Runtime` => click Next and Select "Apache Tomcat" => Finish

Answer (score 1):

It happened that I edited in the listener class and after I saved it and republish the app to tomcat I found that error of class not found.

What I did was to remove my updates in the listener class, republish to tomcat, then add the updates again.. I did this because I suspected that there is a problem in eclipse in .class generation for any reason, although I cleaned the projects several times.

Removing my updates, saving (to have a new compiled version of the class), then adding my updates back again has resolved the issue for me.

Yes this seems illogic, but IDEs issues occur sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

In my case some jar files was missing like
javax.ejb-api-3.2.jar missing
in Tomcat directory in libs folder. also check jars libs of your .m2 repository of  project.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).